# Font rendering problem in KDE

Tags: 13.10, kubuntu, fonts

kUbuntu noob user here.

I feel like I messed something with the font configuration but I'm not sure why. Now I see ugly fonts in all application.

Any idea to restart the font rendering like it was?

Comment: Did you install wine?

Comment: No, but I've installed mscorefonts.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution!!

I'm translating from spanish, maybe the things has diferents names in your desktop.

- "system config" > "applications view" > "fonts type"
- Enable "smoth borthers"
- Choose "configure"
- Use subpixels with RGB and soft "hinting"